# How did Tensorflow process images of ImageNet in Tfrecord format when training resnet?

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, resnet, tfrecord, imagenet

emm, converting imagenet to Tfrecord format is quite complicated, so I downloaded the processed Tfrecord imagenet from somewhere.

I applied it to resnet34 in tensorflow with parameters from Pytorch, but found that the accuracy is just 55%, too low. I guess the reason may be the different methods processing imagenet between Pytorch.models and this Tfrecord. And a nice bro has told me the way how Pytorch processing data, but I still need to know how tensorflow processing it.

I found that the values of Tfrecord pictures range from -1 to 1, can you tell me the processing method of this Tfrecord so that I can try to improve the accuracy?

Thanks a lot! I am just too new_flesh, your kind help is so so important

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, Let me give out my first anser in stackoverflow to myself.

The different way processing images effect the accuracy, that' right.

Pytorch scales pictures to [0,1] and then normalizes them using mean and std.

And the Tfrecord file I found scales pictures to [0,1], and then scale them to [-1, 1] by:

```
image = tf.subtract(image, 0.5)
image = tf.multiply(image, 2.0)
```

(which is a strange way as I see).

So I  add comments to thes two lines, and got a 66% accuracy. By fine_tune, got 72%(But I stiil don't understand the accuracy decline when transfer parameters from Pytorch to Tensoflow).

PS: In this period, I found that parameters set in operator would be saved when saving models in tensorflow, so don't worry about how to set parameter of operator the same.